# symfony 2 global route to perform code on every page

Tags: symfony, routes, symfony-2.7

I am learning Symfony 2.
I try to declare a global route or something which will be perform on every single page. Usually I have 1 route for 1 page or a few pages, but I have no idea how i can setup a "global" route for every page. 
**I just want to perform some code on every single page.**

Is that possible?

Comment: Take a look at kernel event listeners.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/event_listener.html

Comment: I found the official documentation a bit hard to understand specially as a new comer to this concept but you should still read it and also have a look at this resource https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony-journey/event-subscriber, it walks you through the concept of event listners and event subscriber.

Comment: What actually is it that you are wanting to do? As there are a few things you may want to do there are, obviously, a few different answers. If you just wanted to run code before every page it might be event listener based. If you want something "on" every page it may involve including a template, creating a customer Twig method or rendering a sub request to a controller.

Comment: Thank you, i read about the event listener and that is what I need. How can i render a variable from the event listener (kernel) to all templates?

Answer (score -1):

You make a little mistake. There are no global routes but there are indeed possibilities to show same content or code on multiple (all) pages.

Therefor you could start to take a closer look to Twig.

You need to learn about [template inheritance](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#template-inheritance-and-layouts), [including templates](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#including-other-templates) and [embedding controllers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers)

Comment: No sorry but this is not a template issue. reading about kernel event listener did the job.